# Background services for BLE connection

Tags: java, android

I need to implement a background service, that scan via BLE for devices and connect with my BLE device if its discover. So my question is which services should I use ?

- IntentService
- JobSheduler

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a `service` (`IntentService` would serve the purpose as well). The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) captures the primary steps involved neatly. The sample code there uses a `service` to demo API usage:-

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    .........
    .........
    .........
```

Answer (score 1):

Both can solve your problem, it just depends on how you want the scanning to take place. Intent service would only be suitable for one-off scanning were a certain condition is met and you activate the intent service to start scanning but note with intent service after the task of scanning is completed the service is stopped and other life cycle methods follow. So it would only work if there is an external condition that controls when the service should be started. Now job scheduler would involve polling which would be your best case scenario since it would require a continuous polling and would be perfect but you need to consider your timings. Personally i would recommend extending service class and exporting it from manifest so it lives on in the background.